# NameError in Compiled Python Script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nameerror

I tried this code with the Python IDE and worked fine. However, a NameError appeared after I compiled the code using pyinstaller or executed the code in Ninja IDE. Any suggestions?

Here is my code. I'm a beginner so please don't judge!

```
from math import sqrt
while True:
numbers = int(input('Input the total amount of numbers with uncertainties you wish to use: '))
answer = str(input('Type A/a for addition of uncertainties or M/m/D/d for division/multiplication of uncertainties:'))
count = 1
mylist = []
secondlist = []
listsqrnum = []
listsqrun = []
finallist= []
listnum = []
listuncertainty = []
listofanswer1 = ["A","a"]
listofanswer2 = ["d","D","M","m"]
if answer in listofanswer1:
    while count <= numbers:

        num = float(input('Input uncertainty ' + str(count) + ': '))
        count += 1
        mylist.append(num)
    for i in mylist:
        secondlist.append(i ** 2)

    x = sqrt(sum(secondlist))
    print (x)
elif answer in listofanswer2:
        result = float(input("Input resulting value: "))
        while count <= numbers:
            number = float(input("Input number " + str(count) + ": "))
            uncertainty = float(input("Input uncertainty number " +str(count)+ ": "))
            listnum.append(number)
            listuncertainty.append(uncertainty)
            count +=1
        for i in listnum:
            listsqrnum.append(i ** 2)
        for i in listuncertainty:
            listsqrun.append(i**2)
        for i in range(0,len(listsqrnum)):
            finallist.append(listsqrun[i]/listsqrnum[i])

        sumofsquare = sum(finallist)
        squareroot = sqrt(sumofsquare)
        final = result * squareroot
        print (final)
else:
    print("You have not typed anything or you entered a float")
```

The error traces back to line 4, saying NameError - 'a' is undefined.
It also indicates same error as other values within the answer list is inputted.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you by some chance pick up a Python 3.x tutorial but are actually running 2.x?

Comment: Hey. I'm running Python 3.5.1. I learned to code using a Python 3+ tutorial.

Comment: Not with that error you're not.

Comment: At the top of your script add this code, and report back what prints out: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: This is what it prints out: 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?